# How do it trouble shoot a 403 on an Nginx server?

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-config

this is my first attempt at deploying an angular application on Nginx. I have the server setup on an EC2 instance with linux. I have my project downloaded from git in the ec2-user directory. I am able to build and have a dist file present. I am able to get the welcome message and verify the server is functioning.

I am finding many variations of the `nginx.config` file, I either get my project structure listed or a 403 when I go to my address.

I have tried setting the root path in the conf file to my EC2 project path and I have added

```
`location / {
autoindex on;
root /home/ec2-user/web;
try_files $uri /index.html;
}
root         /usr/share/nginx/html;`
```

into my `nginx.config` folder without any success

I have also added permissions to the project folder directory

I continue to get internal server error or forbidden

I suspect I have an issue with the html location but, I really am unable to locate any updated info pertinent to what im try to accomplish.

I am simply attempting to get my application to display

here is my nginx.conf file:

```
    # For more information on configuration, see:
    #   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
    #   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

    user nginx;
    worker_processes auto;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

    events {
         worker_connections 1024;
    }

    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        keepalive_timeout   65;
        types_hash_max_size 4096;

        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type        application/octet-stream;

        # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
        # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
        # for more information.
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        server {
        listen       80;
            listen       [::]:80;
            server_name  _;

            location / {
            #autoindex on;
            #autoindex_exact_size on;
            }

        root /home/ec2-user/angular-ecommerce;

            index index.html;

            # Load configuration files for the default server block.
            include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

            error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /404.html {
            }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
            }
        }

    # Settings for a TLS enabled server.
    #
    #    server {
    #        listen       443 ssl http2;
    #        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    #        server_name  _;
    #        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #
    #        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
    #        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
    #        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    #        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    #        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
    #        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #
    #        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    #        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    #
    #        error_page 404 /404.html;
    #        location = /404.html {
    #        }
    #
    #        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #        location = /50x.html {
    #        }<sub>your text</sub>
    #    }

    }
```